# Predictive Dropdown Input

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a table called `contacts`, where each user stores the username of his contacts:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE sender='".$_SESSION ["username"]."'");
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

My page is used to compose a message to an user. So when a user types in the textfield I need to show a dropdown list matching names from his contacts (as in Gmail).

```
<input name="reciever" type="text" value="" class="inputs3" placeholder="Enter the username"/>
```

I searched a lot, but couldn't find any working script.

Comment: Maybe you searched for the wrong thing? I think `autocomplete select` gives good results. E.g. see http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/autocomplete/ for some jquery plugins. You need to the integration to your server yourself though.

Comment: Just FYI: The native [MySQL-Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future. Consider switching to an alternative (PDO, MySQLi for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this auto complete sample, [Demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625090356/http://jqfaq.com/how-to-prevent-suggestion-while-typing-white-space-in-autocomplete/) / [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLp68/2/)

> ```
> autocomplete({
>         minLength: 1,
>         source: function( request, response ) {
>           //check if the request string starts with a space
>           if(request.term===' ')
>           {
>             response([{value: "Enter Some text to search"}]);
>             return false;
>           }
>           // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
>           response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
>           availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
>         }
> ```

This will give autocomplete coding idea